# F1 Database, choosing between entity or relationship for the standing

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

i'm working on a F1 Database where i want to store datas of a F1 championship, such as driver, team, races and tracks and obviously championship standing(team and driver) and every race standing. My main problem is that i dont know if the standing should be a relationship or an entity, i need to store the position and the points. This problem is for the race and for the championship standing. Thanks

I tried to look for a solution online but i didnt find it.

Comment: Not an f1 fan so no idea what championship standing(team and driver)  might be..you could broaden your appeal by explaining with example.

Comment: In a championship there are 20 or more drivers (every team has 2 drivers, so about 10 team) and they race in 24 races, every race has a standing (position, driver, point gained) the championship standing for the driver is simply the sum of all the points that a driver score in all the races of a championship, while the team championship standing is the standing where the points of a team corresponds in the sum of all the points of the drivers of team (example: Ferrari points will be the points that Leclerc and Sainz score in all races). Hope to be clear

Comment: standing should then be a table consisting of driver race and points with fks to race and driver, the team can be acquired.